# Probability Distributions and Computational Complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

This question is about the intersection of probability theory and
computational complexity. One key observation is that some
distributions are easier to generate than others. For example,
the problem

> Given a number $n$, return a uniformly distributed number $i$ with $0 \leq i < n$.

is easy to solve.  On the other hand, the following problem is or
appears to be much harder.

> Given a number $n$, return a number $i$ such that $i$ is  (the
>   Gödel number of) a valid proof of length n in Peano arithmetic. 
>   Moreover, if the number of such proofs is $pr(n)$,
>   then the probability to get any specific proof of length $n$
>   should be $\frac{1}{pr(n)}$.

This suggests to me that probability distributions come with a notion 
of computational complexity. Moreover, this complexity is probably 
closely related to the underlying decision problems (whether sub-recursive,
e.g. $P$, $EXP$, recursive, recursively enumerable, or worse).

My question is: how does one define the computational complexity of probability distributions, especially where the underlying decision problem is not decidable. I'm sure this has been investigated already, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Another interesting example (but which is decidable)  is the quantum fourier transform.  Given $f(k)=a^k \mod b$ return a number $l \in [0,N]$ such that the probability of $l$ is proportional to $\left|F(l)\right|$, $F(l) = \sum_{k=0}^N f(k) e^{-2\pi ikl/N}$.

Comment: Both of your examples are discrete uniform distributions. I would imagine the differing complexities would be in how hard it is to count $|\chi|$ where $\chi$ is the support.

Comment: @NicholasMancuso I agree that counting + unform choice can always be used. So in some sense it gives an upper bound. Is this all that can be said? Where in the literature has this been investigated?

Comment: seems broad... there are many probabilistic complexity classes & then also the [PCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCP_theorem) thm is quite significant. eg have you heard of [BPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_(complexity))? there are also strong connections to quantum computing... there is a strong argument to be made that probability theory breaks down on undecidable problems because its all about stats/computable math. also [average case complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity)? [PAC learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probably_approximately_correct_learning)?

Comment: @NicholasMancuso The examples I give are uniform distributions. But one can ask the
same question about non-uniform distributions. One can also wonder
about distributions on $\mathbb{R}$. As regards discrete distributions:
prima facie, counting doesn't appear to be enough in general, you also need to be able
to generate the $i$-th element, after you've uniformly chosen
$i$. That said, it might be the case that counting is the core of the
problem.

Comment: Is the [probability simulation theorem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26858) of any help?

Comment: @NikosM. I'm not sure what that theorem is. The link you give doesn't appear to mention it.

Comment: @MartinBerger, the stats.se link actually uses the theorem, the theorem is sth like the one stated [here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ece438/supplements/random_generator.pdf) and [here](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~vose/Publications/random.pdf), this is basic probability results nothing more than that

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks, but that link too doesn't say anything about the complexity of the underlying distribution. The reference talks about a transformation $\phi$ on the uniform distribution. But that transformation might be hard / or easy computationally.

Comment: your question reminded me of this paper. seems related. what do you think? [The halting problem is decidable on a set of asymptotic probability one](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504351) Hamkins/Miasnikov

Comment: @vzn  
Yes, I know that paper. It's another illustration of the difficulty my question is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of probability distributions 
comes up particularly in the study of *distributional* problems like 
[DistNP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#distnp) in Levin's theory of [average case complexity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity).

A distribution is *P-computable* if
its cumulative density function can be evaluated in polynomial time.

A distribution is *P-samplable* if 
we can sample from them  in polynomial time.

If a distribution is P-computable then it is P-sampable.
The reverse is not true if certain one-way functions exist.

You can extend the definitions to other complexity classes.

[Oded Goldreich](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/) has a nice [introductory notes](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/COL/lnd.pdf) on the topic 
that you may want to check.

Comment: Thanks, I think a theory of $P$-samplable distributions is something like what I've been looking for. But there is no reason to restrict attention to $P$, you can define $C$-samplable distributions for any complexity class $C$. With the  recent rise of  [probabilistic programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_programming_language) that is becoming vital.

Comment: @Martin, yes. There was [a tutorial on Probabilistic Programming](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2015/Schedule?event=4892) ([slides](https://media.nips.cc/Conferences/2015/tutorialslides/wood-nips-probabilistic-programming-tutorial-2015.pdf), the video is going to be posted as well) at NIPS 2015. I heard people who attended found it very interesting. Nice to see people working at the intersection of ML/Stats and PL. :)

Comment: Yes, and the main problem is that such languages (= generic, programmable samplers) are slow. How can we speed them up?